# Is the Basic File Upload example in the Django documentation correct?

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I'm using python 3.10.5 with django 4.2.2.

The [`djangoproject documentation for a Basic File Upload`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads) has the following example for uploading a file:

> Consider a form containing a FileField:

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

*views.py*

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UploadFileForm

# Imaginary function to handle an uploaded file.
from somewhere import handle_uploaded_file

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

This is my *upload.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>File Upload</h1>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="file" required>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run that code, it fails the...

```
if form.is_valid()
```

...test in **views.py** because "title" is empty, but it's defined as required in the **forms.py**. If I simply comment out the...

```
title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
```

...line from **forms.py**, then it works fine, so what is that "*title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)*" line for in **forms.py**?

Comment: If you use `{{ form }}` it adds a text field for the title, likely the title you want to provide to the file.

Comment: That did the trick. Now I get it. Thanks so much Willem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by **Willem VO supports mod strike**, simply use **{{ form }}** in place of the...

```
<input type="file" name="file" required>
```

...line in **upload.html**.

NEW *upload.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>File Upload</h1>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```